# How to add a DB restriction - Check constraint or trigger

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to know how can I add a DB restriction on a table. I want to simplify the problem with a table in Oracle Database as

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_STUDENT
(

STUDENT VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
SUBJECT VARCHAR2(38) ,
IS_LANG NUMBER(1,0)
);
```

A student can have any number of subjects but only one of them can be a language (IS_LANG).

Valid data would be

```
Insert into TEST_STUDENT (STUDENT,SUBJECT,IS_LANG) values ('John','Math',);
Insert into TEST_STUDENT (STUDENT,SUBJECT,IS_LANG) values ('John','Science',);
Insert into TEST_STUDENT (STUDENT,SUBJECT,IS_LANG) values ('John','French',1);
Insert into TEST_STUDENT (STUDENT,SUBJECT,IS_LANG) values ('Lily','Math',);
Insert into TEST_STUDENT (STUDENT,SUBJECT,IS_LANG) values ('Lily','English',1);
```

however, I should not be able to insert fresh data like up the table,  something like

```
Insert into TEST_STUDENT (STUDENT,SUBJECT,IS_LANG) values ('John','English',1);
```

or

```
Insert into TEST_STUDENT (STUDENT,SUBJECT,IS_LANG) values ('Lily','French',1);
```

I don't want to introduce triggers here, unless it is the only way around. I want to have this restrictions because in the actual software would have multiple client implementations trying to insert data into this table.

Comment: Side note: Your data model is not correct, as "IS_LANG" is an attribute of the subject itself, not the subject and the student. And it sounds like this ought to be in some way client configurable, so in fact you probably should categorise subjects as languages, sciences, etc in another table and let clients decide how many of each a student can be associated with. And what about studying different languages at different times?

Comment: I would definitely do that in case if the example I mentioned is the actual problem I am solving. I was trying to simplify the actual problem with the above example (apparently not very good one). Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one of the good examples for a partial index.

Unfortunately in Oracle you need a workaround to implement a partial index (other DBMS simply allow a `WHERE` clause to be applied):

```
create unique index idx_one_language 
   on test_student 
      (
          case when is_lang = 1 then student else null end
      );
```

This exploits the fact that Oracle does not index tuples where **all** columns are null. With the above expression only rows where `IS_LANG = 1` will be indexed for each student. As the index is defined as unique, only one such row can exist.

Here is a SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/43394d/1

Comment: You don't actually need the second column/function in that index, I think. Indexing on "case when is_lang = 1 then student else null end" ought to suffice.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thanks a lot.  I wish I finished reading the "Function-Based Indexes" part in "Indexes and Index-Organized Tables" of Oracle Documentation